# What such notation means Dense()() brackets and brackets in python?

Tags: python, keras

I found such notation in keras documatation for dense class:
    predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
    What such notation ()() means?

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# This returns a tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

# a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

# This creates a model that includes
# the Input layer and three Dense layers
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, labels)  # starts training
```

Answer (score 2):

`x()()` means that the call `x()` returns a callable (like a function or a class constructor) that is immediately called again. Think of it as:

```
fnc = x()
result = fnc()
```

A simple example:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        return 'baz'
    return bar

>>> foo()()
'baz'
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dense(...)` creates an instance of the `Dense` class. This instance has a `__call__` operator which is spelled with round brackets.